# php / ajax - Populate dropdown list based on selected option in other dropwdown

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, select

I have a table on my database called "measurements", and another for "units";

The "measurements" table has a column for id and name. The "units" table has a column for id, name and measurement_id.

The idea is that, when the user selects a measurement from the dropdown, it will display then, another dropdown with the units found for that measurement.

I guess I have to do it with "ajax". I have done some basics, retrieving information from a html file, but I don't know how to link that with retrieving information from a database.

On measurement.php:

```
  public function display_measurements() {
      include 'includes/db_connection.php';   
          try {

      $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM measurements";

      $results = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $results->execute();
     } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
        return array();
    }
      return $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

 public function get_units_for_measurement($measurement_id = ':measurement_id') {
       include 'includes/db_connection.php';

       try { 
           $sql = "SELECT measurements.id, units.id, units.name "
               . "FROM measurements "
               . "JOIN units "
               . "ON measurements.id=units.measurement_id WHERE measurements.id=:measurement_id";
           $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
           $result->bindParam(':measurement_id', $measurement_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
           $result->execute(); 
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
        return array();
    }
    return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }
```

Select to display the measurements: (it is part of a bigger form, but the rest is irrelevant, so I have added the form tag just to place you on my code):

```
 <form id="newRecipe" method="POST" action="new_recipe.php">   
 .......
     <label for="measurements" class="required">Measurements</label>
    <select name="measurements" class="selectMeasurement">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select a measurement -- </option>
    <?php
        $measurements = $measurementObj->display_measurements();
        foreach ($measurements as $measurement) {
            echo '<option value="' . $measurement['id'] . '" ';
            echo '>' . $measurement['name'] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select> 

    //display select values based on measurement_id
    <label for="units" class="required">Units</label>
    <select name="units">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select a unit -- </option>
        <?php
        $units = $measurementObj->get_units_for_measurement($measurement['id']);
        foreach ($units as $unit) {
            echo '<option value="' . $unit['id'] . '" ';
            echo '>' . $unit['name'] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select> 
  ..... 
</form>
```

Then, on my scripts I have this to retrieve the selected value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#newRecipe').on('change','.selectMeasurement', function(){
      var selectedMeasurementId = this.value;
      return selectedMeasurementId;
    });   
});
```

But now..... I don't know how to proceed. At the moment, I am returning the value of the measurement_id selected, but how can I "send" that value to mysql query? So, what I don't want is to have to send the form or reload the page to show the select with the units id; so.... that's why I think it must be done with ajax.... right?

Anyone can give me a hint about how to proceed?

Thank you

Comment: Yes - you can and probably should do this with AJAX. Here is a [good tutorial](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to reload page just use ajax with the selectedMeasurementId. $.ajax('/get_units_for_measurement?measurement_id=selectedMeasurementId', function(res) { }); for example

Comment: mmmm I have another doubt....
I am working with php objects, so, when the ajax request is complete I want to do something like:

.complete($measurementObj->get_units_for_measurement(selectedMeasurementId));

But obviously, it says my object is not declared... how can I use the php object to execute the method?

Answer (score 0):

I have another suggestion: fully populate everything with PHP, then use javascript to listen for changes to the selected dropdowns and update the options appropriately.